# Custom Template doesn't output result when set as homepage

Tags: templates

I have duplicated the page.php to create a custome-archives.php
I want to list post titles by category

```
<?php
/*
 Template Name: Archives
 */
get_header(); ?>

<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post' ,
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'category_name'         => 'epson',
'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
); 
$q = new WP_Query($args);
$array = (array) $q;
$posts = $array['posts'];

foreach($posts AS $key => $value){
//value is an object 
$post = (array) $value;


echo $post['post_title']."<br>";
}

?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If I see this page as an individual page, no problem I have the output, but when I set it as the Homepage, I have a blank page.

Comment: Is there a reason you have it set up as a Page? The easiest way to adjust the homepage is to create a `front-page.php` and modify the query rather than adding a new one.

Comment: I am new to Wordpress i didn't know that solution thanks